# Convert non UTF-8 ASCII literals in otherwise UTF-8 text to their respective character

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, cp1252

I have a UTF8 encoded text that has been mangled and contains some 'cp1252' ASCII literals.
I am trying to isolate the literals and convert them one by one, however following code does not work and I can't understand why...

```
text = "This text contains some ASCII literal codes like \x9a and \x9e."

# Find all ASCII literal codes in the text
codes = re.findall(r'\\x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}', text)

# Replace each ASCII literal code with its decoded character
for code in codes:
    char = bytes(code, 'ascii').decode('cp1252')
    text = text.replace(code, char)

print(text)
```

Comment: Why do you think that it does not work?

Comment: It's *really* mangled if it has a 4-character escape sequence instead of the byte the escape sequence is supposed to represent.

Comment: `text` does not contain the 4-character sequence ``\``, `x`, `9`, `a`; it contains the single Unicode character U+009A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No regex needed.  Encoding in `latin1` converts 1:1 from Unicode code points U+0000 to U+00FF to bytes `b'\x00'` to `b'\xff'`.  Then decode correctly:

```
>>> text = "This text contains some ASCII literal codes like \x9a and \x9e."
>>> text.encode('latin1').decode('cp1252')
'This text contains some ASCII literal codes like š and ž.'
```

The text was probably decoded as `ISO-8859-1` (another name for Latin-1) in the first place.  Ideally fix the *that* code to decode as `cp1252`.